# My CouchDB is in a sub directory. What should I list as the cradle host?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

My CouchDB databases are inside of this directory:

http://example.com/couchdb/

For example, I have a CouchDB database "foo" here:

http://example.com/couchdb/foo/

What should I list as the "host" in the cradle setup function?

```
cradle.setup({host: '[what goes here]',
          options: {cache: true, raw: false}});
```

Above example from: https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle

I can't get cradle to see my database...

Comment: Is there any "prefix" or similar option? I've seen `prefix` in other couchdb libraries. 
Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with cradle (keep meaning to learn it).

Comment: Thanks jhs, but I don't see any prefix option.

Comment: Bummer. This is why I personally prefer not to use a CouchDB client and use HTTP. (In NodeJS I like Mikeal's `request` module. *However* I have heard on good authority that Cradle is nice.

Comment: Just to make sure, do your *databases* have a slash in them, e.g. `some/database`, or is the entire CouchDB API embedded (e.g. via reverse proxy) within a namespace inside a URL? Thanks!

Comment: jhs: My database is here: example.com/couchdb/my_database (no slashes in my_database) ...not sure what you need about the embedded part.

Comment: jhs: I ditched cradle and used Mikeal's request. After days of trying to get it to work with cradle, I had it working in 5 min with Mikeal's request.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding IP address of your host as a cradle host option.

Comment: The IP address didn't work. I removed the host option completely from "new (cradle.Connection){}" and now it works.

Comment: @edt: Then you probably listen only to connections coming from localhost on CouchDB port, because that's the default option.

Answer (score 1):

Longshot, I am not confident this will work. I glanced at the Cradle source and it does a lot of string concatenation to build many of its queries.

Try adding the path to the database name, so instead of `/foo` you would have database `couchdb/foo`. At least for database queries (and hopefully document, views, attachments, and everything within that path) it might work.

```
var cradle = require('cradle');
var db = new(cradle.Connection)().database('couchdb/foo');
db.get("some_docid", function(err, doc) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("I got the doc!");
})
```

Sorry, I haven't got the prefixed couch setup to test this directly. Downvotes welcome, edits even more welcome!